# Explanation in Lucene 5.5.2

Tags: java, lucene

I'm creating a custom Weight class for a Query in Lucene, but I have to override method explain that return a Explanation object. I try to create one, but, the only constructor is private. I search in the documentation and there are a statics method that create one Explanation, but this require, at least, another Explanation. How then I can create an Explanation? My Lucene current version is 5.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Explanation.match` and `Explanation.noMatch` are the right methods to be looking at.  The `Explanation...` arguments are child Explanation nodes.  If your Explanation has no children, just don't pass it any of them:

```
Explanation.match(floatScore, "mySimpleScore");
```

For a relatively simple practical example, here is how ConstantScoreWeight constructs it's Explanation, of which the "boost" and "queryNorm" nodes have no children:

```
return Explanation.match(
    queryWeight, getQuery().toString() + ", product of:",
    Explanation.match(boost, "boost"), Explanation.match(queryNorm, "queryNorm"));
```